# Add Padding (safety zone) to leader

Tags: css, printing

I have a table of contents in print with leaders (e.g. the page number at the end)

```
#table-of-contents ol a::after {
    content: leader(space) target-counter(attr(href), page);
}
```

My problem is, that with too long titles, the page number sticks to the text as shown below:

[image]

I want to add a padding to the right side, to avoid the text to get too much to the right.

Unfortunately, anchors are required to be inline elements for the leaders to work.

I get this with `display: inline-block;`

[image]

Max width or padding are not respected with inline. Making them inline-block doesn't fix the problem, since the leaders automatically take their space with `display: inline;`.

I can't apply the padding(or margin) on the before element, this will push the page number to the left, no matter if I add margin or padding to the right or left.

[image]

Any ideas?

Help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The best you can do is give padding and inline-block to the `a` element, then set `width` to 100% and position absolut to the after element. Some like this https://jsfiddle.net/7pcv1puj/1/

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I only took a global look at it, and I saw:

> Unfortunately, anchors are inline elements. Max width or padding are not respected. Making them inline-block doesn't change anything.

You know you can override that?

There's stuff like `display:inline-block;display:block;` and a couple of others?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase it: Unfortunately, **anchors** are required to be inline elements in order to have leaders working. See the updated question please.

Comment: **inline-block doesn't change anything.** is just wrong... https://jsfiddle.net/7pcv1puj/

Comment: Max width or padding are not respected with inline. Making them inline-block doesn't fix the problem, since the leaders automatically take their space with `display: inline;`. @DaniP

Comment: Those properties are respected ... maybe that's not what you want for your layout but are respected. It's better if you add an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
#table-of-contents ol a::after {
    content: leader(space) target-counter(attr(href), page);
    margin-right: -2cm;
}

#table-of-contents {
    width: calc(100% - 2cm);
}
```